# Unable to identify entities based on the intent/utterances in Luis

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have created two intents

1) Search => Goal is to find search phrase from user utterance

[image]

2) Search app  => Goal is to find app name from user utterance

[image]

when I test it with "search book", I am expecting it to match the search intent and give the searchterm entity as "book". But it says no predicted entities. How can this be resolved?

[image]

All the test cases related to search App are working fine and it identifies the appname entity. The model is trained and I see it is green. Is there anything else I need to do to identify the searchterm entity?

Comment: Have you published your LUIS model after training it? Training the model makes the updated model to be accessible within the portal but publishing the model makes the changes available to be accessible in the published slot.

Comment: I am testing from the luis.ai website. You don't need to publish if you are testing in website.